# c# . If (timeElapsed == seconds) When button is clicked after random amount of seconds it has to change color

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to do something like https://www.humanbenchmark.com/ with android xamarin. I'm stuck with converting lifespan to integer? This is my piece of code:

```
private void AfterClicked()
{
    ScreenClickButton.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);     
     Random rnd = new Random();
    int seconds = rnd.Next(1, 11);
    DateTime startTime1;
    startTime1 = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan timeElapsed = DateTime.Now - startTime1;            
    if (timeElapsed == seconds)
    {
        ScreenClickButton.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see that it has a `seconds` property

```
if (timeElapsed.Seconds == seconds)
```

However, this is probably not going to work: you are essentially creating two DateTime objects in a row and comparing them - they will not be identical but will also not differ by any meaningful amount, and certainly not by more than a second.

If you are trying to measure user reaction time, you probably want to establish the benchmark timestamp *before* they click the button, not after.

Comment: This function does not measure time, this function is for green screen to pop up and user will have to click on it as fast as he can.